# Create and export file into .dat and .csv using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, data-uri

I want to create and export a record into .csv and .dat file,
my current code for .csv file is

```
 window.downloadCSV = function(args) {
    var data, filename, link;

    var csv = convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV({
        data: stockData
    });
    if (csv == null) return;

    filename = args.filename || Xrm.Page.getAttribute("name").getValue() + ".csv";

    if (!csv.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
        csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + csv;
    }
    data = encodeURI(csv);

    link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', data);
    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    link.click();
}
function convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV(args) {
    var result, ctr, keys, columnDelimiter, lineDelimiter, data;
        data = args.data || null;
    if (data == null || !data.length) {
        return null;
    }

    columnDelimiter = args.columnDelimiter || ',';
    lineDelimiter = args.lineDelimiter || '\n';

    keys = Object.keys(data[0]);

    result = '';
    result += keys.join(columnDelimiter);
    result += lineDelimiter;

    data.forEach(function(item) {
        ctr = 0;
        keys.forEach(function(key) {
            if (ctr > 0) result += columnDelimiter;

            result += item[key];
            ctr++;
        });
        result += lineDelimiter;

    });

    result += "Total";
    result += columnDelimiter;
    result += columnDelimiter;
    result += columnDelimiter;
    result += totalAmount;
    result += columnDelimiter;
    result += totalHash;

    return result;
}
```

the above code is working in .csv file, but for .dat file it produces a file with content of one line of text instead as data table.

For .dat file, I'm setting the filename and csv as

```
filename = args.filename || Xrm.Page.getAttribute("name").getValue() + ".dat";
csv = 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + csv;
```

Can someone give me an advice with this.

[image: expected result]

[image: current result]

Comment: Windows notepad uses `\r\n` as it's line delimiter, are you sure you have done that? Seems like the default is `'\n'` in your function.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. I've been stuck with this for one whole day. It solved my problem. Thanks a lot.